# different but valid google shorten url?

Tags: web-services, google-api, jbehave

Recently, I'm running an JBehave demo for the Web Service API test. During the example, it calls the Google Shorten URL service. After the execution, i noticed that errors throws:

java.lang.AssertionError: id
Expected: aaa
     got: bbb

That's interesting for me, coz indeed i verified that both works. So the second one, i manually got from https://goo.gl/, and the first one, i guess the code calling the Google Shorten URL service directly. So, could anybody shed some light what's going on here? i searched but no clue yet. Thanks all!

Comment: aaa: http://goo.gl/rKjyzq

Comment: bbb: http://goo.gl/Tm1UX

Comment: Google Shorten URL service: https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url